# How can i set up credentials as an environmental variable in windows?

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

I'm currently working on an academic project in my university and im trying to access IEX Cloud API (iexfinance) for financial data extraction using python but i keep running into an authentication error.
When i checked the documentation of the package it recommends to set Secret Authentication Key as an environmental variable using 'IEX_TOKEN' to authenticate my request which i dont know how to do.

Also, i should note that i'm very new to the world of programming so thank you in advance for any assistance.

Here's a snippet of the script i use:

```
tickerSymbol = input("Ticker Symbol: ")
companyInfo = Stock(tickerSymbol)
stockPrice = companyInfo.get_price()

start = datetime(sy,sm,sd)
end = datetime(ey, em,ed)

historicalPrices = get_historical_intraday(tickerSymbol, start, end)

stockHistoricals = pd.DataFrame(historicalPrices).T
```

Comment: Do you have access to the Secret Authentication Key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the secret authentication key. Try:

```
#import os module in first line of your code
import os
#set the env vairable in 2nd line
os.environ['IEX_TOKEN'] = 'TheSecretAuthenticationKey'

#other imports
...
...
...
...
#remaining code
```